# Reload lot of pictures of webcam

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a new website project, i have a lot of webcam, the original source reload all seconds.

I have make a website to collect all webcam on one website.

I post the source code, but no reload, or no picture.
If it reload with use a timestamp (with "*.jpg?=XXXXX), the img tag, reload .jpg img and not the timestamp).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
   =D
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cam</h1>
    <div id="grille" .col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12>
        <ul>
            <?php
                try {
                    $bdd = new PDO('mysqlXXXXXXXXXXXX);
                }
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                }
                $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM XXXXXX');
                while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
                    ?>
                    <li class="img_cams col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                       <img id="<?php echo $donnees['num_cam']; ?>" src="<?php echo $donnees['src']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $donnees['title']; ?>" title="<?php echo $donnees['title']; ?>" />
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                $reponse->closeCursor();
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <script src="bootstrap/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php
            try {
                $bdd = new PDO('mysqlXXXXXXXXXXXX);
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM XXXXXX');
            while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
                ?>
                function loadImage(imgID, address) {
                    document.getElementById(imgID).src=''+address;
                }

                setInterval(function() {
                    loadImage("<?php echo $donnees['num_cam']; ?>", "<?php echo $donnees['src']; ?>");
                }, 1000);
                <?php
            }
            $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>

        /* OLD SOURCS OF JS IN EXEMPLE */

        /* OK mais pas de refresh
        setInterval(function() {
            var imgCam = document.getElementById('706'); imgCam.src = 'http://XXXX/rt706/snap_c1.jpg';
            var imgCam = document.getElementById('709'); imgCam.src = 'http://XXXX/rt709.jpg';
        }, 2000);
        */

        /* OK mais blanc
        setInterval(function() {
            var imgCam = document.getElementById('img_cams');
            imgCam.src = 'rt709.jpg?' + Math.random();
        }, 2000);
        */
        /* OK mais blanc
        function refresh() {
            var imgCam = document.getElementById("img_cams");
            imgCam.src = imgCam.src + 'rt709.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            setInterval(refresh,2000);
        };
        */
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="grille" .col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12>`

I believe you intended to have the other properties wrapped within a `class=""` attribute.

Also, your question is unclear. Do you have the webcam pictures (which should just be considered the same as regular picture files) stored somewhere else, or are you looking to load the user's webcam (with their permission) and allow them to take pictures?

If you're looking to access a user's webcam, take a look at the following url: 
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

Here is a snippet of the code they've provided on the website down to the essentials:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
 var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {
    // do something
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

From the author:

> Once you've added this code, save your HTML document and preview your page. Provided you are on a supported browser, you should see your webcam video stream after you've given your browser permission to access it.

Comment: Thx. It's not a stream movie, it's a traffic webcam, and picture reload all seconds, no video flux.. I test this.

Comment: I test with the Snippets, but it's not work. My source is not a video, just a motion picture, reload all second.
Yes this is an ID and not a CLASS because the JS accept just ID type..